# Issue with reading data from a txt file

Tags: java, numberformatexception, reader

I am reading most of the data from text files. This time, I have happened to have some issues with reading the data array from a .txt file. I am providing some part of the code as follows:
MWE:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Model {
    public static final int Y = 7;
    public static final int K = 42;
    public static final int T = 10;

public static class Sleg {
        // private int id;
        private int i;
        private int j;
        private double l;

        public Sleg(int i, int j, double l) {
            // this.id = id;
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
            this.l = l;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Integer.toString(i) + " " + Integer.toString(j) + " " + Double.toString(l);
        }
    }


    public static void dataGen() {

 List<Sleg> slegs = new ArrayList<Sleg>();
    File slFile = new File("slFile.txt");

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("slFile.txt"))) {


        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] numbers = line.trim().split(" ");
            int i = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
            int j = Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
            double l = Double.parseDouble(numbers[2]);
            slegs.add(new Sleg(i, j, l));
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(slFile.toString() + " does not exist.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle any possible IOExceptions as well...
        System.out.println("Unable to read : " + slFile.toString());
    }

    System.out.print("slegs = [");
    for (Sleg s : slegs) {
        System.out.print("[" + s + "] ");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
Zat[][] u = new int [slegs.size()][T];
File zatFile = new File("zat.txt");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("zat.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            for (int sl = 0; sl < slegs.size(); sl++) {
                String[] ln = line.trim().split(" ");
                for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {
                    Zat[sl][t] = Integer.parseInt(ln[t]);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to find : " + zatFile.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read : " + zatFile.toString());
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           System.out.println("not an integer"); 
       }
    System.out.print("Zat = [");
    for (int sl = 0; sl < slegs.size(); sl++) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {
            System.out.print(" " + Zat[sl][t] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
    System.out.println(
            "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");


    }
}
```

And as I run the code, an error is popping up as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0    0"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Model.dataGen(Model.java:832)
    at SolverMethod.main(SolverMethod.java:9)
```

The sFilefile:

```
1 2 400
2 5 800
5 7 450
2 3 800
3 6 550
3 4 500
4 5 500
7 5 450
5 4 500
4 3 400
6 3 550
3 2 700
2 1 400
5 2 800
```

And the zat file:

```
1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

I had some other arrays of slegs and other integer ranges and I did not have any issue. I would appreciate your recommendations.

Comment: Time to use your debugger to step through your code just prior to the exception to see what is going on. It seems like your splitting of the lines of text is not working as you're expecting, and the fastest way of finding out why is to do intense debugging.

Comment: As the error message says: "0____0". What number should "0____0" be? As HFOE says, step through this with a debugger and all should be clear.

Comment: Since you've not posted a valid [mcve] or even indicated which line is `Model.java:832`, the line that  throws the exception, I'm not sure if we can offer any more advice than has been given.

Comment: My guess is that you have something that is not a space (maybe a tab?) separating two of your numbers (the "0    0" that you quote.  Change your `split(" ")` to `split("\\s+")` to split on any sequence of whitespace (not just spaces). and try again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see four spaces in your data files, but the error message is 'For input string: "0    0"'
I guess you have a tabulation in your file. You do not see it in your editor, but it might was converted to four spaces.
Try to replace your

```
split(" ");
```

to

```
split(""\\s+""); \\ Thanks for the comment, I did not think about several whitespace characters.
```

"\s+" will understand several spaces and the tabulations as well.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Much better: `.split("\\s+");` since you want to greedily capture *all* the whitespace between numbers

Comment: Oops, as noted by moilejter previously in comments to the original post

Comment: I appreciate all your comments. .split("\\s+") instead of  .split(" ") actually resolved the issue. I think it might be because I had copied & pasted the array data from Excel into .txt file, and although I had fixed the space b/w each of the numbers, the reader could not realize it.